# How to replace href url with other url in html document using erlang?

Tags: html, url, replace, erlang, href

I have a html document and I have to replace all href url with another url using Erlang. I am beginner for erlang. Can any one help me on this?

Comment: I tried to search on google but nothing I got till now...

Comment: I meant show us the code you have so far with a hole where you need help..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions for it.  There is 're' module in erlang and you can use `replace/3`

eg.

```
re:replace("kuba","b","[&]",[{return,list}]).
```

gives you:

```
"ku[b]a"
```

http://schemecookbook.org/Erlang/RegexChapter
doc for replace/3
http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#replace-3

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Jakub it helped me and got the idea and resolved my problem but...need 1 more help... I have a html content and I have to replace href with my href so I am replacing href=" to href="my url here. SO at the place of & also its replacing href="...Cud u please help me how to escape & in erlang. Thanks

Comment: try using "\&" in your regular expression